# Bottom of the page is missing on load

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, locomotive-scroll

I have a strange issue on Firefox when I'm trying to load my page https://lefutoir.fr/

I miss the last part of the bottom which then reapper when I reload the page.
I'm using locomotive scroll on it and I'm pretty sure its linked to that but I have no clue why it's acting like that.

Any ideas about that ? Thanks a lot !